# What games represent sports well?

Tags: game-recommendation

I hear Clash Bowley is working on a new baseball-themed RPG.  I've often thought how fantasy football fans are inches away from actually playing an RPG about sports.  What RPGs out there are about sports, or have a pretty good treatment of it?  There have been many sports mini-games inside RPGs over time (my first RPG adventure, Crash on Volturnus for Star Frontiers, had a lengthy mounted polo-type game sequence, and I remember the Challenge of Champions D&D adventure series from Dungeon) but are there any games that treat it as a main part of the action and not a sideline?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [**XCrawl** setting](http://www.goodman-games.com/xcrawl.html) for the d20 system posits a world where D&D-style adventurers take part in a *Running Man*-style competition/reality show televised for an alternate-modern audience in world where Rome never fell and fantasy monsters exist. The entire game is based around what is, essentially, an athletic endeavor in the style of modern sport — right down to endorsement deals and referees. The rules have an "athlete" class to supplement the usual d20 fantasy fare.

Comment: Many of the XCrawl products were on sale for $1-$2 in Paizo's Black Friday sale, and I bought a batch of them, they should be in my hot little hands soon!

Comment: @mxyzplk Darn — I missed that.  Maybe next time. :)

Answer (score 3):

[Piledrivers & Powerbombs](http://www.princeofdarknessgames.com/pnp/index.htm) is a game of TV-style professional wrestling, with a focus on in-ring play, but also including all the posturing for the camera, deliberately-created drama, and spontaneous grudge matches that pro wrestling TV is famous for.

(Sprinkle scare quotes in there as necessary, depending on your opinion of pro wrestling TV.)

Answer (score 1):

Contenders is Boxing. I haven't read it, just the blurbs, so I can't say much more than that.

Street Fighter is Fantasy/Chanbarra Martial Arts themed. Treats it as a tournament-driven setting. Each adventure is supposed to be the action before the tourney, and then ending with the Tourney in town.

Comment: Contenders is excellent. Some love: http://story-games.com/forums/comments.php?DiscussionID=1518&page=1#Item_18